# FFserver command not found even install ffmpeg

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, computer-vision, ffserver

i follow instruction to install the ffmpeg (https://github.com/udacity/nd131-openvino-fundamentals-project-starter/blob/master/linux-setup.md)

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

However, it does not install ffserver together while it should be after searching on internet.

Below is my system configuration

```
Ubuntu 18.04
Python3.7 
ffmpeg 4.2.2
```

Command i want to execute

```
sudo ffserver -f ./ffmpeg/server.conf
```

Expected

```
ffserver version x.x.x.x.....
```

Current result

```
ffserver command not found
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg's FFServer feature has been removed from the main release.

You'll have to bring up and older version of FFmpeg and install that.

Here are some instructions:

https://superuser.com/questions/1296377/why-am-i-getting-an-unable-to-find-a-suitable-output-format-for-http-localho/1297419#1297419

Also if you use Docker you can use this version of the Alpine distro. The apk version of ffmpeg is a bit older so using the below Dockerfile actually installs an ffmpeg version that has ffserver.

```
FROM alpine:3.8
RUN apk add curl bash ffmpeg && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY ffserver.conf /etc/ffserver.conf

ENTRYPOINT [ "ffserver" ]
```